# What is the most land efficient food source?

Tags: fallout-4

After reading some [tips on settlement defense](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243731/12035), it seems like having a [small walled inner-base](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/243778/12035) is optimal. To this end which crops take up the least space?

Comment: If you downvote, please say why. This is a reasonable question. [Don't downvote for no reason](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11038/why-are-fallout-4-questions-getting-so-many-down-votes?cb=1).

Comment: Downvoting is completely discretionary. I downvoted because you can test this yourself. In about 2 minutes. One of the legitimate downvote reasons is "shows no research effort".

Comment: It is definetly worth pointing out that physical size seems to make little differance. I can spread Mulfruit out across roughly the same space as corn, even with the trees clashing with each other, and the corn restricted to roughly 2x the space between them.

Comment: Asking for reasons for downvotes generally makes more happen.  If no one gives you a reason, it's because [Tim lost his keys again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/193762).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mutfruit are slightly larger than many of the other crops, but give +1 food, instead of the +0.5 food provided by all other crops. This makes them the most efficient for both space and number of settlers that need to be assigned.

In order to meet the food requirements for the maximum 21 settlers, three settlers can tend 18 Mutfruit for +18 food, leaving a fourth settler to be assigned to either 3 more Mutfruit, or 6 other crops.

Other crops might add variety, including the components required to make Vegetable Starch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure which crop takes up the least space, but if it comes to efficiency, Mutfruit is by far the most efficient. It is the only crop that yields 1 food per unit, as opposed to every other crop, which yield only 0.5 food. Mutfruit also doesn't take up particularly much space, though it might require slightly more space than Corn or Carrots.

Since Mutfruit produces twice the food per unit, it's also the most workforce efficient. As each settler can tend to at most 6 units of crop, a single settler can produce 6 food worth of Mutfruits instead of 3 food worth of any other crop.

Comment: Even though Mutfruit is the most efficient crop, you might still want to grow Corn and Tato. The reason for that is because you need Mutfruit, Corn, and Tato to cook starch, which can then be processed to adhesive, which is one of the most needed components and not very common, making it one of the most valuable materials (along with oil).

Comment: Note that workers can work 6 units of food, and not 6 units of plant-providing food. This means that no one food source is more efficient from a worker stand point. A worker can work 6 mutfruit plants, 12 tomato plants, or any other combination resulting in 6 total food..